# why kernel assigns 250 as a major number in device driver

Tags: drivers

I recently stated working on device driver development. Initially, I build a simple driver and application. The thing which I notice are that every time when I inserts my module, kernel assign a major number 250. I wants to know why always it assigns 250 ?? Other thing that I wants to know that I have generated my device file using command "mknod". What about if I want a create a permanent device file in my device memory that remains in it even after shutdown?

Any idea would be really appreciated.

Comment: 240-254 is the range for local/experimental use. Why 250 exactly always, I don't know.

Comment: Are these numbers depend upon which device drivers you are working or something else?
I am working on char drivers. Is because of that, I got always 250?

Answer (score 1):

250 is taken by default, when you have not specified the Major number while registering the device or while creating the node (mknod).

For Ex: To register a Character device driver, the function syntax is

```
register_chrdev(Major Number, Name of the driver, File operations);
```

This has to be done in module_init calling function.

To create a node, after you load that module is

```
sudo mknod -m 666 /dev/char_driver c 240 0
```

Here,

- 666 - permission
- char_driver - name of the driver (can be of any name)
- c - Says that its a character driver
- 240 - Major number (same as if in register_chrdev)
- 0 - Minor number.

This should probably work.

Comment: 250 is taken by default??? Why? I mean to say that why not in between 240 - 254?